# com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex 5

Tags: java, android, gradle

This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    applicationId "com.android.****"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.0-rc1'
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner         "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    exclude 'org/apache/*' // for duplicate use in chatKit
    exclude 'org/apache/http/version.properties'
    exclude 'org/apache/http/client/version.properties'
    exclude 'org/apache/http/entity/mime/version.properties'
}

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
        } else {
            dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        }
    }
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g" // 2g should be also OK
}
}
ext {
supportVersion = '25.3.1'
picassoVersion = '2.5.2'
circleImageViewVersion = '2.1.0'
shapeImageViewVersion = '0.9.3'
circleindicatorVersion = '1.2.2@aar'
}
dependencies {

implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
// MaterialTextField
implementation 'com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.7'

// Network monitoring
implementation 'com.novoda:merlin:1.1.6'

// Volley http library
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

// Pretty Toast
implementation 'ua.com.crosp.solutions.library:pretty-toast:0.2.0'

// PageIndicatorView
implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.0'

// Material About
implementation 'com.github.jrvansuita:MaterialAbout:0.2.0'

// rebound
implementation 'com.facebook.rebound:rebound:0.3.8'

// CircleImageView
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

// Customizable Timeline View for Android
implementation 'com.github.qapqap:TimelineView:v1.6'

// Android Chart
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'

// ChatKit for Android

// implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:chatkit:0.2.2'
implementation "com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:$shapeImageViewVersion"

// Utils
implementation "me.relex:circleindicator:$circleindicatorVersion"

// Picasso
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

// Android View Animations
implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'

// Java WebSockets
implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}

// Android library project for cropping images
implementation 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation project(':chatkit')

}
```

Top-level build file:

```
       // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

   buildscript {

       repositories {
           google()
           jcenter()
           maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
           maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha01'
           // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.14.1'
           classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
           classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.8.0' // for chatKit library
       }
   }

   allprojects {

       repositories {
           google()
           jcenter()
           maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
           flatDir {
               dirs 'libs'
               dirs project(':app').file('libs')
           }

       }

   }
   task clean(type: Delete) {
       delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
```

The ocmplete error I get when compiling the project is:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

The complete error is as follows:

```
    * Exception is:
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 29 more
    Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:127)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 41 more
    Caused by: com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList$MainDexListException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BestMatchSpec
    at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:87)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:114)
    ... 44 more
    Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BestMatchSpec
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.resolveClassConflictImpl(ProgramClassCollection.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.lambda$create$0(ProgramClassCollection.java:25)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.create(ProgramClassCollection.java:24)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.LazyLoadedDexApplication$Builder.build(LazyLoadedDexApplication.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:122)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:86)
    at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:36)
    at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:95)
    at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:83)
    ... 45 more
```

**Edit 2:**

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication {
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
 .
 ..
 ...
 ....
```

Comment: Do you have `MultiDex.install(this);` in your application class ?.

Comment: @sunilsunny yeah.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the **same problem**. One thing you can try is `Clean Project` and then `Rebuild Project`. 
It worked for me.

Comment: I do it. But the problem is still there

Comment: try it `gradle :app:assembleDebug --stacktrace`

Answer (score 2):

Try clean android studio cache from `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`.
it worked for me